# Epoxy/Adhesive to bond solid wood and acrylic

Tags: mechanical, epoxy

I am trying to bond solid wood with with clear acrylic, with requirement to able to withstand shearing force, not more than **6kg over an area of 100 sq.cm**.

Have tried to bond with result of the Acrylic side getting shear off. Has anyone used better epoxy for the job? Thank you in advance!

Comment: what glue did you use?

Comment: Araldite the standard type. (https://www.horme.com.sg/product.aspx?id=1585&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu_jYBRD8ARIsAC3EGCL8Apm0TV0M3pTKzp3DxbzE19-TLT8sJhkUf46m_4ZtiOANX-HzWnAaAh1hEALw_wcB)

Comment: What surface preparation did you do to the acrylic? I find when gluing to a smooth plastic surface, a little time spent with sandpaper to roughen up the interface, followed by making sure *all the dust is gone*, will significantly strengthen your joint, especially in shear

Comment: I have not done pre-processing on the acrylic surface. Thanks for your suggestion and I would definitely try to sand it using coarse sandpaper. Have been wondering fine or coarse surface is better for araldite bonding.

Comment: Epoxy will not stick to acrylic, use a two part methacrylic adhesive to bond them. You can find this glue at Home Depot, it's called Plastic Welder.  It stinks though, try not to breathe the fumes !